# New application with multiple UI : WPF and Mobile website (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf

I am in the first step of the design of an application that would support two completely different UI, and I would like to do it with the minimum duplication of code.

The first UI would be a windows application (probably with WPF), that will be the most used, the second would be a web application accessed mainly through mobile devices.

Knowing that the WPF application have to work completely disconnected from the network
 and that once in a while, it must be possible to synchronize the work done offline in a central server

## Here is what I was thinking to do:

### WPF version:

MVC style WPF application, SQL server compact/express on each workstation and entity framework for data access, organize so that the WPF model, the entity model, and the controllers are in a separate assembly.
In addition, we will need a SQL Server database to synchronize the work of everybody.

### Web version:

This is where things get blurry in my mind:
If I do an asp.net MVC application, modify it so that it is mobile friendlier, do you think it is possible to reuse the model, entity model, controllers, validation, etc. ?

I am still in the early stage of the design, and I am not familiar with asp.net MVC, so if you have other solutions, that would help a lot.

Also I will create and post here a POC when I will have a good design, so that it can be reused.

Comment: look at this sample, http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/ already doing what you are thinking of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

- Build a Service Layer (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) using TDD (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) to encapsulate the functionality of your application.
- Build a remote facade (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html) on the service layer to service remote clients (WPF, Andriod, iPnone, WP7 etc etc)
- Read up on MVVM and Prism4 (http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) before starting the WPF app.
- Build the ASP.NET to access the service layer directly/in process.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: So you would go for a classic ASP.NET ? Does that means that I can't reuse the validation ?

Comment: I think he's saying that both sides would share the WCF service and data objects, but build the desktop version with the MVVM design pattern, and build the web version with MVC

Comment: I'm not advocating one type of ASP.NET over another, that's up to you.  And I'm definitely NOT saying that the web app would use the Remote Facade (for which on .NEt the obvious choice is WCF), exactly the reverse, the service layer is not remotely available and should be consumed in process by the web app.  The Remote Facade would expose the service layer remotely to the WPF app.  Your domain model (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) should include contrainsts, your UI should include validation inline with these constraints. Unsure how you might get reuse of your val. code

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing in WPF then forget ASP for your web based code. Structure it using MVVM pattern.

It's not a vast step change to have the same WPF application switched to be browser based (that's part of the point for WPF), certainly far quicker than writing a second app. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663364.aspx) for information about WPF (applications and browser).

What form of data transfer is required - have you considered MSMQ for passing data to the server. This then wouldn't care if there was a connection or not and once there is data would be transferred without any work on your part.

Comment: When you say "It's not a vast step change to have the same WPF application switched to be browser based", are you talking about XBAP ? The issue here is that I can't consider XBAP for the web/mobile solution : it only works on windows, with .net framework installed, while I have to support *all* systems/browsers (b.e. safari on IOS).